What are some good cybersecurity models on HuggingFace that I can customize and use with a custom agent?
I've been having trouble setting up my agent because the tools that I try using don't have the necessary maping to use with the custom agent.
`\`OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[10\], line 4
1 from langchain.agents import load_huggingface_tool
\----\> 4 tool = load_huggingface_tool("elftsdmr/malware-url-detect")
6 print(f"{tool.name}: {tool.description}")


554 except ImportError:
555     raise ImportError(
556         "HuggingFace tools require the libraries `transformers>=4.29.0`"
557         " and `huggingface_hub>=0.14.1` to be installed."
558         " Please install it with"
559         " `pip install --upgrade transformers huggingface_hub`."
560     )
\--\> 561 hf_tool = load_tool(
562     task_or_repo_id,
563     model_repo_id=model_repo_id,
564     token=token,
565     remote=remote,
566     \*\*kwargs,
567 )
568 outputs = hf_tool.outputs
569 if set(outputs) != {"text"}:
...
267         )
268     custom_tool = config\["custom_tool"\]
269 else:

OSError: elftsdmr/malware-url-detect does not provide a mapping to custom tools in its configuration `config.json`.
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...\`

`
This is the error that I keep getting.
Do you guys know of any models on HuggingFace that I can use without running into issues?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
